# Angular 2 ngFormControl with Attribute Directive on same input

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, form-control

I have a FormControl like this:

```
<form [ngFormModel]='controlGroup' novalidate>
    Amount <input type="text" dmAmount [ngFormControl]="formControls.value">
</form>

this.controlGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   value: [this.newItem.value, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+[wm]?$')])],
});
```

`dmAmount` attribute directive mutates the value and it does change inside the input:

```
//some code
this.elRef.nativeElement.value = +num * 12;
```

However the submitted value is still the original as if attribute directive didn't change it. How can I make sure the value does change in the form model so I could submit the new value?

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your code

```
private myVal: number;
```

And assign an ngModel in your view

```
<form [ngFormModel]='controlGroup' novalidate>
    Amount <input type="text" dmAmount [(ngModel)]="myVal" [ngFormControl]="formControls.value">
</form>
```

your method should update your myVal variable instead of the native element directly. It looks like you're doing this in NativeScript so you will need to run the update through NgZone like this

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {}

// Your code
this._zone.run(() => this.myVal = +num * 12);
```

This should update your your view. Then use the myVal variable for submission (or in your case, replace myVal with this.newItem.value)